# Why does Object.prototype.toString return constructor function name on some objects?

Tags: javascript

Let's say we do this:

```js
function Dog(name, breed) {
  this.name = name;
  this.breed = breed;

}

var date = new Date();
var dog = new Dog("YOU'RE", "READING");

var zehbi = Object.prototype.toString.call(date);
var zehbi2 = Object.prototype.toString.call(dog);

console.log(zehbi);
console.log(zehbi2);
```

Why does `zehbi` return the name of its constructor function "Date" but `zehbi2` doesn't return the name of it's constructor function "Dog" but returns "Object" instead?

Comment: May I ask what you are trying to achieve here? Because the toString function for Object (the built-in type for objects) returns what type of object it is as a string with the format [object Type]. This is exactly what you are seeing in your code. Maybe you wanted to call toString()?

Answer (score 1):

Because it is defined that way in the specification:

> [**20.1.3.6 Object.prototype.toString ( )**](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-object.prototype.tostring)
> When the `toString` toString method is called, the following steps are taken:
>
> 1. If the `this` value is `undefined`, return "[object Undefined]".
> 2. If the `this` value is `null`, return "[object Null]".
> 3. Let `O` be ! ToObject(this value).
> 4. Let `isArray` be ? IsArray(O).
> 5. If `isArray` is `true`, let `builtinTag` be "Array".
> 6. Else if `O` has a `[[ParameterMap]]` internal slot, let `builtinTag` be "Arguments".
> 7. Else if `O` has a `[[Call]]` internal method, let `builtinTag` be "Function".
> 8. Else if `O` has an `[[ErrorData]]` internal slot, let `builtinTag` be "Error"`.
> 9. Else if `O` has a `[[BooleanData]]` internal slot, let `builtinTag` be "Boolean".
> 10. Else if `O` has a `[[NumberData]]` internal slot, let `builtinTag` be "Number".
> 11. Else if `O` has a `[[StringData]]` internal slot, let `builtinTag` be "String".
> 12. Else if `O` has a `[[DateValue]]` internal slot, let `builtinTag` be "Date".
> 13. Else if `O` has a `[[RegExpMatcher]]` internal slot, let `builtinTag` be "RegExp".
> 14. Else, let `builtinTag` be "Object"
> 15. Let `tag` be ? `Get(O, @@toStringTag)`.
> 16. If `Type(tag)` is not `String`, set `tag` to `builtinTag`.
> 17. Return the string-concatenation of "[object ", tag, and "]".

And for `Date` the point **12.** is true because it has an `[[DateValue]]` internal slot, your `Dog` does not match any of the **5.** to **13.** so **14.** is used. After that **15.** checks for the existence of `@@toStringTag` which does not return a string for `Dog` or `Date`, so the `tag` becomes the `builtinTag` given by one of the  **5.** to **14.**.

Comment: I have no clue what those terms refer to, what do,terms like 'o' and 'ToObject' mean?

Comment: @handsome-and-SKINNY [`ToObject`](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-toobject) `[...]converts argument to a value of type Object[...]` which are described in the Table in the link. Or in other words: it normalizes what you pass to `Object.prototype.toString.call()` to be an actual Object for the case when a primitive is passed, if it is already an object that object itself is returned. And `O` is therefore is either the object you passed to `call` or the Object that represents the same value as the primitive passed to `call`.

Comment: `ToObject(1)` would return `new Number(1)` and `val new Number(1) = ToObject(val)` would return that `val` passed to `ToObject`. `typeof 1` is `number` and `typeof new Number(1)` is `object`, but both represent the value `1`.

Answer (score 1):

The result of [`Object.prototype.toString()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/toString) is determined by two things:

- The type of built-in object it is executed against. The specification determine what built-ins will be identified as and a Date will say `"[object Date]"`.
- As of ES6 - the well-known symbol [`@@toStringTag`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Symbol/toStringTag).

For the normal objects, prior to ES6 the default `toString()` would only produce `"[object Object]"` while post ES6 the result is the string `"[object @@toStringTag]"` by using the value of the symbol. By default the value for the symbol is `"Object"`.

You can override it for a custom class:

```js
function Dog(name, breed) {
  this.name = name;
  this.breed = breed;
}

Dog.prototype[Symbol.toStringTag] = "Dog";

var dog = new Dog("YOU'RE", "READING");

var zehbi2 = Object.prototype.toString.call(dog);

console.log(zehbi2);
```

Or any object:

```js
var obj = { 
  [Symbol.toStringTag]: "Custom" 
}

console.log(Object.prototype.toString.call(obj));
console.log(obj.toString());
```

You can even override it for built-in objects:

```js
var obj = new Date()

obj[Symbol.toStringTag] = "Custom";

console.log(Object.prototype.toString.call(obj));
```

Comment: Alright, so in "[object Type]", Type will produce the value assigned to the Symbol.toStringTag property. So in an example: if toString is called on an array and it returns "[object Array]", that would be because by default the Symbol.toStringTag property has an assigned value of "Array" inside of Array.prototype . Is this correct?

Comment: @handsome-and-SKINNY no, for built-ins there is a special check. [See the spec quoted by t.niese](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71227188) - steps 4. and 5. define that if it's an array, then "Array" will be used. It's possible for some requirement to also add a @@toStringTag to arrays but it is not required by spec. In FF `[][Symbol.toStringTag]` returns `undefined`.

Comment: ^ "some requirements" = "some environments"